# How to use 2D ConvNets on 3D data

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have just started to study ConvNets and I have a question on how to train them.

Actually what I have understood is that one can use a CNN to extract features from images, even on pictures that are different from those used to train the network.

Since I would like to use a ConvNet (such as Vgg or Inception), I would also like to start from a trained network and continue its training in order to improve the weights using my dataset.

The problem is that I have 3D data and the most powerful CNNs are designed to use 2D data! Is there a smart way to feed the 2D ConvNet with 3D data which is not a raw averaging of the slices of the 3D images?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your 3D data to 2D by just concatenating the slices (you put them together in one large 2D image).